# Class 'PHPJasper\PHPJasper' not found?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have an app with Laravel 5.4.9 an PHP 7.0.2.

I installed I need to install PHP Jasper, from this url: https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper by running

```
$ composer require geekcom/phpjasper:~1.16
```

followed by running

```
$ composer install
```

I believe I have installed it correctly, but when I try to use below code :

```
use PHPJasper\PHPJasper;
```

It throws following error:

> FatalThrowableError in MyController.php line 714:
>
> Class 'PHPJasper\PHPJasper' not found

How can I fix this?

Comment: composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: Odin Thunder also tried

Comment: By the way, there's no need to run `composer install` immediately after you successfully ran `composer require vendor/package`.

Comment: Look at the file vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php and check if lines for geekom & phpjasper exists

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out at https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper#the-hello-world-example, you need to initialize the composer autoloader first by requiring `vendor/autoload.php`.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPJasper\PHPJasper;

$jasper = new PHPJasper;
```

Since it appears you have some sort of web application, you probably have some entry point, a front controller perhaps. Require `vendor/autoload.php` there, and adjust the path to it to match your directory structure.

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading.

Comment: He's using Laravel, no need to require autoload since it's already done by Laravel

Answer (score -1):

You might need to just include the direct relative path

```
require_once __DIR__ . 'vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/src/PHPJasper.php';
```

> DIR, in this case, points the project root